# Pandas.DataFrame: How to sort rows by the largest value in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as in the figure (result of a word2vec analysis). I need to sort the rows
descendingly by the largest value in each row. So I want the order of the rows after sorting to be as indicated by the red numbers in the image.

Thanks

Michael

[image: original dataframe and desired sequence]

Answer (score 1):

Find max on `axis=1` and sort this series of maxes. `reindex` using this index.

Sample `df`

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0  95  86  29  38  79  18
1  15   8  34  46  71  50
2  29   9  78  97  83  45
3  88  25  17  83  78  77
4  40  82   3   0  78  38

df_final = df.reindex(df.max(1).sort_values(ascending=False).index)

Out[675]:
    A   B   C   D   E   F
2  29   9  78  97  83  45
0  95  86  29  38  79  18
3  88  25  17  83  78  77
4  40  82   3   0  78  38
1  15   8  34  46  71  50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.max(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) to find the row-wise max and then use [`.argsort()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) to return the integer indices that would sort the Series values. Finally, use `.loc` to arrange the rows in the desired sequence:

```
df.loc[df.max(axis=1).argsort()[::-1]]
```

(`[::-1]` added for descending order.  Remove it for ascending order)

**Input:**

```
      1     2         3         4
0  0.32 -1.09 -0.040000  0.600062
1 -0.32  1.19  3.287113  0.620000
2  2.04  1.23  1.010000  1.320000
```

**Output:**

```
      1     2         3         4
1 -0.32  1.19  3.287113  0.620000
2  2.04  1.23  1.010000  1.320000
0  0.32 -1.09 -0.040000  0.600062
```